Calculating the most influential set of source nodes on a target node when a source node's signal is propagated
I am mainly posting for guidance, as I don't know where to start looking in order to solve the following problem:

Given a directed graph G with edge weights between 0 and 1. As well as a set of source nodes, each associated with signal strength between 0 and 1. Sort the source nodes by how much of their signal reaches the target node.

Some notes are:

The algorithm does not need to return a sorted list of all nodes at once, as I believe that would be an NP-Hard. But instead return only the top $n$ of the list.
In order to be clear in terms of propagation, if a source node has a signal strength of 0.8, and it passes through an edge with a weight of 0.5, the signal becomes
$0.8 × 0.5 = 0.4$ after that edge. The goal is to measure the total signal reaching the target node from each source.

I believe the problem is similar to those that can be solved via network flow and influence maximization problems, but it is different enough that none of those algorithms can be used as cookie-cutter solutions for it. I am wondering if anyone here has run into something similar in practice or literature, and if so, what it is called or where I should start looking.
Thanks in advance.

Where did you encounter this problem?  Can you credit the original source where you saw this?  Please define how the values on the edges and nodes determine "how much of the signal" reaches the target node.  I don't know what it means for a source node to "pass through" an edge.  It's also not 100% clear how cycles affect the amount of signal that reaches a node.  Can you use mathematics to specify the problem?
